# read url with hash symbol by django

Tags: django

I have this function:

```
def facebook_forward(request):
    return HttpResponse(request.build_absolute_uri())
```

When I get to this page with for example:

> http://myapp.com/?a=a

The function returns me the the same url, but when I get to this page with:

> http://myapp.com/#?a=a

it returns me:

> http://myapp.com/

How can I get the text after the hash symbool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant. The part after `#` can not sent to server.

Part after `#` is called as `fragment identifier`is and only used by the browser

> The Fragment component of the URL is the end of the URL from the hash
>   symbol (#) onward. URL Fragments are never sent to the server in the
>   HTTP request— only JavaScript running in the page can see them. So,
>   when your browser loads the URL above, the server sees only
>   “http://www.facebook.com” in the request, and it’s the responsibility
>   of JavaScript in the returned page to examine the URL to find the
>   extra information in the Fragment.

source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/05/16/url-fragments-and-redirects/